# Extend wireless network range seamlessly using an old router

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

I'm going to be moving into a house of years of apartment living. The thing is that all the networking is in the basement and I have a 3 floored house. Now, I have bought a new Wi-Fi router (dual band ac) which is more powerful but not enough so that the 2nd floor gets connectivity. There's an ethernet port that runs up to the second floor; My question is, is there any way to connect my new router to the one on the second floor and make a seamless wireless network so that I don't have to change my network if I take my laptop upstairs. I know this is possible on a larger scale since my university already does this but I wanted to know if this was possible on a smaller scale.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are a few possibilities but I suggest this:

1. Put the new router at the cable box, with DHCP turned on. Set it's IP address to 192.168.n.1. Set DHCP to start assigning addresses at 192.168.3
2. Put the old router upstairs  with DHCP turned off. Set it's IP address to 192.168.n.2
3. connect the two routers by plugging the Ethernet cable into a *LAN* port on both routers.
4. Set all the wireless settings for both routers the same, but assign different channels to the two routers.

I have a similar setup with 3 routers, but set it up a couple of years ago. I believe the above covers all the necessary steps.